# Generate table using formula

Tags: luatex, programming, luacode

What is the simplest most universal way to generate a table using a formula? Minimal amount of code that is most robust. I simply want to essentially generate a table of values where the values are generated by a mathematical formula. I don't want to spend more time trying to code the table than it takes to do it by hand or it would be pointless.

Comment: Please provide some examples of the types of formulas and the ranges of inputs for `x` and `y` you’re interested in. Otherwise, there's simply no basis for applying your criteria "simplest" and "most universal", let alone "minimal amount of code that is robust".

Comment: The question has fuzzy boundaries. The simplest, universal, minimal with no metrics to compare. It will evoke different associations based on knowledge and experience.
Yet, to me, the answer is so obvious!

Comment: On the other hand, I have seen many well-formed MWEs that get quick and excellent responses to the point, but will fail when using real data, longer sentences, changing geometry, or even font size.

Why? Because the MWE was skin-and bones to begin with ---the questioner being unaware of the complexity that lay ahead---, and the answerer did not interpret  what the real question should has  been,

Comment: @SimonDispa I find it quite insane that they would delete my reply but not his. It goes to show you the lack of critical thinking and blind authoritarian mindsets of some of these people. If you don't lick they boot then you are an enemy to them. They only care about licking the boot. Of course it really has to do with them simply being able to exert control over others and nothing to do with logic, facts, right and wrong. See, they will delete this comment too. Probably ban me. That is how their minds work. [Not sure if you saw my reply to Mico or not, now it is gone]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way with `nicematrix` and the mathematical computations done with the floats of `expl3` (which respect IEEE754).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \MyFunction } { m m }
  { \myfunction:nn { \int_use:c { c@#1 } } { \int_use:c { c@#2 } } }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \myfunction:nn
  { 
    \fp_eval:n 
      { 
        trunc(    
         sqrt(#1*7)*(2+#2) % <---- function here
         , 3) 
      } 
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

$\pAutoNiceMatrix[code-before = \cellcolor{red!15}{3-3}]{6-6}{\MyFunction{iRow}{jCol}}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

There are several possibilities, here is a simple loop shown setting a table of sum of squares and a multiplication table

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\zi
\newcount\zj

\newcommand\zz[1]{%
\makebox[1.2cm][r]{$\the\numexpr#1\relax$}%
\ifnum\zj=9 
  \zj=0
  \advance\zi 1
  \par
\else
  \advance\zj 1
\fi
\ifnum\zi<10 \afterfi\zz{#1}\fi}

\def\afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \zz{\zi*\zi+\zj*\zj}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
 \zz{\zi*\zj}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you modify this to be able to accept row and column parameters so that it is more general? (I had to use xparse and tiks(pgfmath stuff) to get it to work)  Also suppose I want to output text such as ordered pairs: \zz{(\zi, \zj)} This fails because it is not a "math expression"(even though technically it can be). Any way to make it easy to do such expressions without screwing up basic expressions(without making it more complex to do simple expressions)?

Answer (score 3):

This is MWE of a lualatex contribution.

[image: tri]

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex    
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{luacode} 

\begin{luacode*}
    function trigtable ()
    for t=0, 45, 3 do
      local x=math.rad(t)
      sf =[[%2d$^{\circ}$ & %1.9f & %1.9f & %1.9f & %1.9f \\]]
      tex.print(string.format(sf, t, x, math.sin(x), math.cos(x),   math.tan(x)))
    end
    end
\end{luacode*}  

\begin{document}    

\newcommand{\trigtable}{\luadirect{trigtable()}}    

\begin{tabular}{rcccc}
    \hline
    & $x$ & $\sin(x)$ & $\cos(x)$ & $\tan(x)$ \\
    \hline
    \trigtable
    \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

From

The PracTEX Journal, 2013, No. 1
*Numerical methods with LuaLATEX*,
Juan I. Montijano, Mario Pérez, Luis Rández and Juan Luis Varona

---

Using Lua as a programing language and LuaLaTeX you can divide the tasks of calculating the table content from the format.

For example
to go from the rather crude table shown earlier to, say, the final table to be publish, having

1. larger headings, stretched cells, alternate coloring of rows (best done in LaTeX)

and

2. 5 degrees steps from 0 to 120 degrees, 4 rounded (not truncated!) decimals and  deal with tan(90 degress) (best done in Lua)

the changes are trivial in the Lua part.

For the LaTeX formatting I used the package `nicematrix` that allows to make the formatting with directives,  without touching the table cells and minimum coding.

[image: x2]

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex    
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{luacode} 

\begin{luacode*}
 function trigtable()
    local t
    for t = 0, 120, 5 do
        local x=math.rad(t)
        if t == 90 then
            sf =[[%2d$^{\circ}$ & %1.4f & %1.4f & %1.4f & \infty \\]]
        else
            sf =[[%2d$^{\circ}$ & %1.4f & %1.4f & %1.4f & %1.4f \\]]
        end
        tex.print(string.format(sf, t, x, math.sin(x), math.cos(x), math.tan(x)))
    end
 end
\end{luacode*}  

\begin{document}    

\newcommand{\trigtable}{\luadirect{trigtable()}}   

\begin{NiceTabular}{rcccc}[
    first-row,
    code-for-first-row = \Large,
    code-before = \rowcolors{1}{blue!3}{},
    cell-space-top-limit = 5pt,
    cell-space-bottom-limit = 5pt
        ]
    \hline
     & $x$ & $\sin(x)$ & $\cos(x)$ & $\tan(x)$ \\
    \hline
    \trigtable
    \hline 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```